# Copied ssl cert to a test site, how do I remove it?

Tags: http, ssl, drupal, https, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I copied my site to a new virtual server with Softlayer but when I did the the security cert came to. now every time I try to log to my new development site it give warnings saying that the site has taken its cert from another source.

I am using Drupal and cant find where to delete or modify the file to remove this warning.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://www.drupal.org/https-information has some information on how to use SSL certs in drupal specifically.

Since you didn't provide the actual error your browser is giving you, I'm going to guess its a domain name mismatch error (like this https://www.digicert.com/ssl-support/certificate-name-mismatch-error.htm ). Basically you will either need to access your site via the domain name that the certificate was signed to, or get a new certificate for your new domain name.

I hope that helps point you in the right direction.